# MongoDB aggregate query in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jpa, aggregate

let me give you some background first:

i have a mongo query that works like a charm

```
db.itemX.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: {
        $in: ["1234","5678"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$attributeValues"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "attribute",
      localField: "attributeValues",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "attributeValues.attributeValue"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "attributeValues.attributeId": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$attributeValues.attributeValue.attribute",
          0
        ]
      },
      "attributeValues.attributeValue": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$attributeValues.attributeValue.number",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "attributeName",
      localField: "attributeValues.attributeId",
      foreignField: "attribute",
      as: "attributeValues.attributeName"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "attributeValues.attributeName": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$attributeValues.attributeName.value",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      attributeValues: {
        $push: "$attributeValues"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This is returning this json

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1234",
    "attributeValues": [
      {
        "attributeValue": "1",
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex1"
      },
      {
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex2"
      },
      {
        "attributeValue": "2",
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex3"
      },
      {
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex4"
      },
      {
        "attributeValue": "2",
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex5"
      },
      {
        "attributeValue": "2",
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5678",
    "attributeValues": [
      {
        "attributeValue": "1",
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex1"
      },
      {
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex2"
      },
      {
        "attributeValue": "2",
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex3"
      },
      {
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex4"
      },
      {
        "attributeValue": "2",
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex5"
      },
      {
        "attributeValue": "2",
        "attributeId": "thisIsHexID",
        "attributeName": "Ex6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is exactly what im looking for. Now, going to java i have this in my repo

```
@Repository
public interface MaterialRepository extends MongoRepository<CategoryMaterial, String> {



    @Query(value="{ 'material' : ?0 }")
    CategoryMaterial findByPrdIdentifier(String prdIdentifier);

    @Query(value="{ 'prdIdentifier' : ?0, 'userId' : ?1 }",
            fields = "{'prdIdentifier': 0,'account': 0,'data': 0,'userId': 0}")
    CategoryMaterial findDocument(String prdIdentifier, String userId);

    @Query(value="{ 'userId' : ?0 }", fields = "{'pcfDocument': 0}")
    List<CategoryMaterial> findByUserId(String userId);

    @Aggregation(pipeline = {"{\n" +
            "    $match: {\n" +
            "      _id: ?0\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    $unwind: \"$attributeValues\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    $lookup: {\n" +
            "      from: \"attribute\",\n" +
            "      localField: \"attributeValues\",\n" +
            "      foreignField: \"_id\",\n" +
            "      as: \"attributeValues.attributeValue\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    $addFields: {\n" +
            "      \"attributeValues.attributeId\": {\n" +
            "        $arrayElemAt: [\n" +
            "          \"$attributeValues.attributeValue.attribute\",\n" +
            "          0\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      \"attributeValues.attributeValue\": {\n" +
            "        $arrayElemAt: [\n" +
            "          \"$attributeValues.attributeValue.number\",\n" +
            "          0\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    $lookup: {\n" +
            "      from: \"attributeName\",\n" +
            "      localField: \"attributeValues.attributeId\",\n" +
            "      foreignField: \"attribute\",\n" +
            "      as: \"attributeValues.attributeName\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    $addFields: {\n" +
            "      \"attributeValues.attributeName\": {\n" +
            "        $arrayElemAt: [\n" +
            "          \"$attributeValues.attributeName.value\",\n" +
            "          0\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    $group: {\n" +
            "      _id: \"$_id\",\n" +
            "      attributeValues: {\n" +
            "        $push: \"$attributeValues\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }"})
    AggregationResults<CategoryMaterial> findAllAggregated(String prdId);
```

But this piece returns this

```
[
    {
        "mappedResults": [
            {
                "material": "1234",
                "category": "1111122222",
                "attributeValues": [
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "rawResults": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "_id": "1234",
                    "category": "111112222",
                    "attributeValues": [
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID"
                    ],
                    "_class": "com.api.sdldb.model.CategoryMaterial"
                }
            ],
            "ok": 1.0
        },
        "serverUsed": null,
        "uniqueMappedResult": {
            "material": "1234",
            "category": "11112222",
            "attributeValues": [
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "mappedResults": [
            {
                "material": "5678",
                "category": "11112222",
                "attributeValues": [
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID",
                    "thisIsHexID"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "rawResults": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "_id": "5678",
                    "category": "111122221",
                    "attributeValues": [
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID",
                        "thisIsHexID"
                    ],
                    "_class": "com.api.sdldb.model.CategoryMaterial"
                }
            ],
            "ok": 1.0
        },
        "serverUsed": null,
        "uniqueMappedResult": {
            "material": "5678",
            "category": "111112222",
            "attributeValues": [
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID",
                "thisIsHexID"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

To sumarize, seems that my query is not doing aggregation as it should and it is returning lots of unncessary code that i dont really need. To give more information, i have 3 collections in mongo, 1 of materials, one for attributes and one to get names based on attributes.

Im almost sure my java query is wrong, im missing something there or i just put the code in wrong order when moving mongodb query to java code.

Thanks for your help and sorry for such long post

PS: @Indybee i guess you mean like this, right? just for simplicity

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {
        "{ '$match': { '_id': ?0 } }," +
        "{ '$unwind': '$attributeValues' }," +
        "{ '$lookup': { 'from': 'attribute', 'localField': 'attributeValues', 'foreignField': '_id', 'as': 'attributeValues.attributeValue' } }," +
        "{ '$addFields': { 'attributeValues.attributeId': { $arrayElemAt: [ '$attributeValues.attributeValue.attribute', 0 ] }, 'attributeValues.attributeValue': { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$attributeValues.attributeValue.number', 0 ] } } }," +
        "{ '$lookup': { 'from': 'attributeName', 'localField': 'attributeValues.attributeId', 'foreignField': 'attribute', 'as': 'attributeValues.attributeName' } }," +
        "{ '$addFields': { 'attributeValues.attributeName': { $arrayElemAt: [ '$attributeValues.attributeName.value', 0 ] } } }," +
        "{ '$group': { '_id': '$_id', 'attributeValues': { '$push': '$attributeValues' } } }"})
```

Regards

Comment: The `pipeline` attribute in the @Aggregation annotation accepts an array of stages. Try separating each stage of `@match`, `@unwind` `@lookup`, etc as separate strings in the `pipeline` attribute

Comment: @indybee replied and added code just above at the end of the topic :)
Thanks